# Swift. create a banner while receive a remote notification when screen is not in background

Tags: swift, background, notifications, banner

Below are the code I have when receive notification. I know I can use PFPush to create a alert, but I feel that it is not a good way. Is there a way to create a banner instead of alert?

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("getMessage", object: nil)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
        //PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
}
```